# Windows Server 2016 - how do I migrate non-clustered Hyper-V VMs to a new cluster?

Tags: windows, hyper-v, windows-server-2016, cluster

I just created a cluster with a single node to which I need to move all of our VMs so I can rebuild the other server and add it to the cluster.  I've set up shared storage and configured hyperv on the cluster node to use that shared storage.  Can I just use the hyperv manager to move the VMs from the old machine to the new one now or do I have to do something else to make each VM cluster aware so they will failover properly?

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 Options:

1) Move VM to clustered Hyper-V host and after that add to cluster.

2) Add “old server” to new cluster. If shared storage is connected to both nodes – you can perform LiveMigration or Quick Migration of VM. Then evict old “server” from cluster, update it and join again.

3) Use V2V converter, which can automatically migrate from one Hyper-V to another. Overview of converters - [here](http://www.vmwareblog.org/v2v-converters-overview/)

P.S. Researching your question, I’ve found the webinar related to your issue - https://www.starwindsoftware.com/learn-how-to-migrate-hyper-v-clusters-smoothly